# How to migrate selective data from one database to another in oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I want to migrate data from Production env to UAT env. But I don't want to migrate all the data from each table. Rather, I wish to migrate only selective data of any particular table using select col1, col2 from tab1 where "any condition";

There is an option of migrating complete data from Oracle SQL Developer. But it migrates entire data.

Suppose the following:

ProductionDB has table1 with columns col1, col2 and col3 
I wish to migrate the data from table1 as 'select * from table1 where col1 = "some value"' to UAT database.

Please suggest some ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious easy answer is create a new table with your CTAS, and migrate THAT new table.

Or on the database copy wizard in SQL Developer, use the global where clause predicate feature to insert your WHERE to apply to all tables being copied.

[image]

If you're using SQL Developer to do the actual moving of data work, keep in mind what you're asking it to do...if you're moving a LOT of data, that's a lot of I/O and network traffic to move that data.

If possible look at something more robust like Data Pump, which also allows you to add WHERE clauses to use for getting the data out.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you tell me where can I find the database copy wizard on Oracle sql developer.

Comment: Tools, Database Copy